# What is the background of "Der Fischer und der Boss" by Reinhard Mey?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

The German singer-songwriter Reinhard Mey has a song called "Der Fischer und der Boss", which translates to "The Fisherman and the Boss".

It tells the story of a fisherman who sometimes goes out for tourists so they can fish too. The boss comes to him although it is bad weather and the fisherman doesn't want to go out, so the boss raises the pay so far the fisherman can't resist any more. He says the fisherman's youngest child has a big religious event coming to her and he would need money for that etc.

Well it ends as you would expect. A little later a lifeboat finds the lifebelt of the sunken boat since the weather was far too heavy.

Here is a link to the [song text](https://www.songtexte.com/songtext/reinhard-mey/der-fischer-und-der-boss-73da06a5.html)  on songtexte.com.
And here it is on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZrBmi4Trck)

So my question is: Is there a real life background to this story? I think I remember him mentioning Michelin announcing the song in a concert, too.

Comment: Albeit not a "real life background" and something you might already be aware of, but the title is certainly reminiscent of the fairytale about ["The Fisherman and his Wife"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fisherman_and_His_Wife), which might share some motifs with the song in that his wife constantly makes the fisherman ask for increasingly bigger wishes from a magical fish, until they ask for too much. It might as well be a coincidence, though.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably never read this, but I found an answer after googling it: it is, I would think, based on the incident mentioned in these articles:

https://www.taipeitimes.com/News/biz/archives/2006/05/28/2003310455

https://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/veteran-tyre-boss-francois-michelin-dies--81750

However, the circumstances seem to be more complicated than the song implies . . . but you should probably read it yourself and form your own opinion.

Comment: From the [*Independent*](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/mystery-surrounds-michelin-man-s-death-on-fishing-trip-off-brittany-480189.html): "Mystery surrounds the death of Edouard Michelin ... in the shipwreck of a small fishing boat off Brittany ... M. Michelin's body was found eight miles off the Breton coast on Friday night. He had persuaded M. Normant - against his gut instincts - to take him fishing for sea bass, despite poor visibility and a heavy swell. The French coastguard said, however, that conditions were reasonable at the time of the shipwreck."